# Html Helper not working with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an `enum` I want to turn into a `DropDownList` for registration purposes I am currently using:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel => InputModel.Input.UserProffesion.GetValues(typeof(Mindfull8User.Proffesion)).Cast<string>())
```

And I am getting an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
> (active)  **CS0176**  Member '**Enum.GetValues(Type)**' cannot be accessed with
> an instance reference; qualify it with a type name
> instead   Mindfull8   c:\Users\User\source\repos\Mindfull8\Mindfull8\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Register.cshtml 53

How do I solve this?
Thanks

The Data Model:

```cs
namespace Mindfull8.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<Mindfull8User> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<Mindfull8User> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<Mindfull8User> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<Mindfull8User> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;     
             
        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<Mindfull8User> userManager,
            IUserStore<Mindfull8User> userStore,
            SignInManager<Mindfull8User> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Max characters is 255")]
            [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Max characters is 255")]
            [Display(Name = "LastName")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Gender")]
            public bool? Gender { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Proffesion")]
            public Proffesion UserProffesion{ get; set; }


            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

`Register.cshtml`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" name="FirstName" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName">First Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" name="LastName" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.LastName">Last Name</label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             
               
                <div class="form-floating">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.Input.UserProffesion ,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")
                   </div>   
                  
              <div class="form-floating">
            </div>
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
```

The User model is:

```cs
public class Mindfull8User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime LastOnline { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public bool? Gender { get; set; }

    public Proffesion UserProffesion { get; set; }
    public enum Proffesion
    {
        Doctor,
        Paitent,
        Proffesor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the [HtmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.getenumselectlist?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that returns a select list for the given type?

For example, if  the `Proffesion` is the given `enum` type:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.UserProffesion,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")
```

Comment: Ive reviewd the code, while it does display a drop down list on the page. it also disconnects it from the InputModel and breaks registration as such, if theres a way to fix that would be great ive tried to do 
`@Html.DropDownList(Input => Input.(Html.GetEnumSelectList<Mindfull8User.Proffesion>()), "Select Role")`
and it does not work, error CS1001

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: Provide more detailed code, especially of the view data model and the view itself, please. This can help to simulate exactly your problem.

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: You can still use the `Html.DropDownListFor()`method with your _data model_. It will be look like `@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel =>Html.GetEnumSelectList<Mindfull8User.Proffesion>(), "Select a value")`. Let me known if you still have a some problem.

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: Try to use the `@Html.DropDownListFor(...)` from my previous comment, please.

Comment: thanks so much for, ive used your soultion and it request a 'optionLabel' how would you add that? thanks!

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: I see. The property that contains the required value inside the data model is `UserProffesion`. It's correct? If _YES_, the correct syntax is `@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.UserProffesion,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")`. This is why we asking to include all related code to the question. Try to apply the update above, please.

Comment: Yeah sorry for he delay, ive tried your syntex and it sends a CS1061 error (RegisterModel does not contain UserProffesion. Since InputModel Input is nested inside RegisterModel, and InputModel Contains UserProffesion. After scrambling around ive found `@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.Input.UserProffesion ,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")` I hope this does not break registraion, will update further after trying around

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: This is possible, because of you didn't provide all related parts of code - only you can check compilation result. Therefore, you need to adapt code from my answer to your real data model. On my test application this is working, at least. If you need any help related to this post add your code (especially the data model declaration) and I'll glad to help you.

Comment: @RephaelKurziner: Sorry, seems to me the `@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.Input.UserProffesion ,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")` is correct code. Do you still have the compilation error?

Comment: Yeah It works, Thanks for all the help victor! <3